# Spark cannot resolve column

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, py4j

While running below code getting the error..it is azure Data bricks hands on EDA.

```
df_typed = spark.sql("SELECT cast(Price as int), 
   cast(Age as int), cast(KM as int), FuelType, 
   cast(HP as int), cast(MetColor as int), 
   cast(Automatic as int), cast(CC as int), 
   cast(Doors as int), cast(Weight as int) FROM usedcars_CSV")

df_typed
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o204.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Price`' given input columns: [default.usedcars_csv._c3, default.usedcars_csv._c6, default.usedcars_csv._c5, default.usedcars_csv._c1, default.usedcars_csv._c7, default.usedcars_csv._c0, default.usedcars_csv._c9, default.usedcars_csv._c2, default.usedcars_csv._c4, default.usedcars_csv._c8]; line 1 pos 12;
'Project [unresolvedalias(cast('Price as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('Age as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('KM as int), None), 'FuelType, unresolvedalias(cast('HP as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('MetColor as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('Automatic as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('CC as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('Doors as int), None), unresolvedalias(cast('Weight as int), None)]
+- SubqueryAlias `default`.`usedcars_csv`
   +- Relation[_c0#347,_c1#348,_c2#349,_c3#350,_c4#351,_c5#352,_c6#353,_c7#354,_c8#355,_c9#356] csv

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$6.apply(TreeNode.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$6.apply(TreeNode.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$8.apply(TreeNode.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$8.apply(TreeNode.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300)
```

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your question. Please review it and [edit] as needed. It's probably going to be closed soon, as you don't provide enough information to reproduce the problem. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Add the table definition. Do you actually have a column called `Price`?

Comment: your df dose not have price.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL, you are trying to convert the price column to int. The data in the price column could contain $ or £ (price notation). So this needs to be handled.

1. Convert the column to text/string
2. Remove $ or £ or any special characters from the data
3. Convert the outcome to int

Example: cast(replace(cast(price as string),'$','') as int)

Thanks.